# Difference between talking about collection $\{G_\alpha\}$ of open sets and finite collection of $G_1,\dots,G_n$ of open sets

Tags: general-topology, notation, metric-spaces, definition

> **Question:** What is the difference between talking about "Any collection $\{G_\alpha\}$ of open sets" and "Any finite collection of $G_1,\dots,G_n$ of open sets"?

I imagine they are highlighting the difference betweem finite and infinite collections. But I see no such point, since the first could be finite.

Is there reason for this wording?

---

This is from Rudin - PMA. Theorem 2.24:

For any collection $\{G_\alpha\}$ of open sets, $\cup_\alpha G_\alpha$ is open.

For any collection $\{F_\alpha\}$ of closed sets, $\cap_\alpha F_\alpha$ is closed.

For any finite collection $G_1,\dots,G_n$ of open sets, $\cap_{i=1}^n G_i$ is open.

For any finite collection $F_1,\dots,F_n$ of closed sets, $\cap_{i=1}^n F_i$ is closed

Comment: It looks like you're looking at the axioms of a topology.  They are presented here in a twofold redundant way.  You can say all in terms of open sets:  arbitrary unions of open sets are open and finite intersections of open sets are open.

Since a closed set is the set complement of an open set, using DeMorgan's laws, the axioms just mentioned translate into the other two.

Comment: The difference relies solely on the fact that when you say any collection, it means that it might as well be an infinite collection. If you are reading that book, check the example that follows or think why does the intersection fails in the infinite case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first could indeed be finite, but this wording emphasises that the collection need not be finite - whereas when the wording "for any finite collection" is used, this is a necessary condition for the conclusions of the theorem to hold.